# troubleshoot 26 lines of simple Get request in php using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to connect to an API using php. I keep getting an error.  I have this code in index.php inside C:\xampp\htdocs\CURLAPI
error "stdClass Object ( [err] => error processing given inputs from request )"
HERE IS THE API.   https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/sentiment-analysis
HERE IS MY CODE

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://api.deepai.org/api/sentiment-analysis";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Api-Key: quickstart-QUdJIGlzIGNvbWluZy4uLi4K",
  'text: ' . 'This is good'
));
$resp = curl_exec($ch);

if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
echo $e;
}
else {
$decoded = json_decode($resp);
print_r($decoded);
}
curl_close($ch);
?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the 'text' parameter as part of the headers, where you should be sending them as a POST request. Try this instead (untested!)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Api-Key: quickstart-QUdJIGlzIGNvbWluZy4uLi4K"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [ 'text' => 'This is good' ]);
```